# iframe : handle onkeypress event

Tags: javascript, iframe

**first code**

```
var my_iframe = document.getElementById("my_iframe");

my_iframe.contentDocument.head = "<script type='text/javascript'>function my_f(e){alert('hey here i am.')}</script>";
my_iframe.contentDocument.body = "<input onkeypress='return my_f(event)'>";
```

Giving me an error `my_f` undefined function.
As I have inspected html element in firebug, found that **my_f function** is defined in javascript tag inside the head of iframe.

could someone guide me, how can handle onkeypress event on input here inside iframe.
And what is wrong here?

---

**second code** :: this worked:

```
my_iframe.contentDocument.body = "<input onkeypress=\"alert('hello');\">";
```

but question here is what is the problem in **first code**;

Comment: `</javascript>` should be `</script>`

Comment: Ya, I am having script tag